# Perfect forwarding and the scope of temporary objects

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, move

In an attempt to realize perfect forwarding for the `*` operator I constructed the following example.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    std::string name;
    A(const A& _other)  : name(_other.name) {
        std::cout << "Copy-Construct with name: " << name << std::endl;
    }
    A(A&& _other)       : name(std::move(_other.name)) {
        std::cout << "Move-Construct with name: " << name << std::endl;
    }
    A(std::string _name): name(_name) { }
};

A operator*(const A& _lhs, const A& _rhs) {
    std::cout << "Start Operator Copy with: " << _lhs.name << " " << _rhs.name << std::endl;
    A bla(_lhs.name+" "+_rhs.name);
    return bla;
}

A&& operator*(A&& _lhs, const A& _rhs) {
    std::cout << "Start Operator Move with: " << _lhs.name << " " << _rhs.name << std::endl;
    _lhs.name += " "+_rhs.name;
    return std::move(_lhs);
}

int main() {
    A a("a");
    A b("b");
    A c("c");
    A d("d");

    A x = a*b*A("t1")*c*A("t2")*A("t3")*d; 

    std::cout << "Final result is: " << x.name << std::endl;
}
```

The result is as I hoped, in particular only one move constructor and no copy constructor is called.

```
Start Operator Copy with: a b
Start Operator Move with: a b t1
Start Operator Move with: a b t1 c
Start Operator Move with: a b t1 c t2
Start Operator Move with: a b t1 c t2 t3
Start Operator Move with: a b t1 c t2 t3 d
Move-Construct with name: a b t1 c t2 t3 d
Final result is: a b t1 c t2 t3 d
```

Now my question is: Is this leagal `C++11` code? In particular can I rely on the fact that the first temporary object (contructed from a and b) leaves its scope at the semicolon and not before that? And is the construction, to return an object obtained as a move reference back as a move reference, legal at all?

Comment: Which temporary object are you referring to?

Comment: The first overload leaks memory - that is definitely not "perfect" in any sense of the word. Both overloads should return by value instead.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ooups sorry, that was another test case. I corrected it. The output was correct never the less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A&& operator*(const A& _lhs, const A& _rhs) {
    std::cout << "Start Operator Copy with: " << _lhs.name << " " << _rhs.name << std::endl;
    A* bla = new A(_lhs.name+" "+_rhs.name);
    return std::move(*bla);
}
```

This creates a dynamically allocated object, so the caller is responsible for deleting it. Your example fails to do that, so leaks memory. This is a terrible function. It should return by value instead, which will be faster because you don't allocate the object on the heap.

```
A&& operator*(A&& _lhs, const A& _rhs) {
    std::cout << "Start Operator Move with: " << _lhs.name << " " << _rhs.name << std::endl;
    _lhs.name += " "+_rhs.name;
    return std::move(_lhs);
}
```

This doesn't lead to memory leaks, so isn't totally obviously wrong like the first one, but it's still wrong. If you call it with a temporary object it returns a reference to that same temporary, but that can lead to dangling references:

```
A&& c = A("a") * A("b");
```

The reference `c` is bound to the temporary created by `A("a")` but that does out of scope at the end of the statement. Any attempt to use `c` has undefined behaviour.

Both overloads should return by value.

You might also want an overload for the case where the left-hand side is an lvalue and the  right-hand side is an rvalue, as that allows you to re-use the right-hand side object. And if you add that you also need an overload for the case where both operands are rvalues. Basically, look at how `std::string` defines `operator+`

Comment: Yes the first is obvious, I forgot to change it back (see my Edit). To save the result as move reference is indeed nasty. :/ But is that the only flaw of this construction? I.e. am I save to use it unless I try to save a move reference of the result?

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to write a function that is only safe if used safely, and is subtly undefined otherwise? If you are implementing move semantics for your type then presumably moving is cheap (otherwise don't bother supporting move semantics) and so just doing `return _lhs;` to return by value is safe and will use the move constructor. Returning a dangling reference is playing with fire and some day in the future someone (maybe your future self) will curse you for it.

Comment: yes... your most like right about that. Its only that I would really like the get rid of this "cheap" overhead of calling the move constructor each time. :/

Comment: Have you actually measured that it's a problem? If not, writing unsafe functions to avoid some imagined problem is the wrong priority IMHO.